# Android Identify SMS message in Broadcast receiver listening for Delivered SMS action

Tags: android, sms

I have an Android app that sends a small queue of messages in a single batch. I am assuming that I can listen for the SENT action and that the send confirmation will be in the same order as the messages were presented to the SMS service. However I am also assuming that delivery confirmation will be asynchronous. How do I identify which message the broadcast receiver is getting delivery confirmation for?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How do you send your messages? Whit the [SmsManager.sendTextMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) you can specify an Intent for every single SMS where you could check if the message was send successfully. So just make a new class instance for every sms.

Comment: Hi, If you will forgive me, that feels a little clumsy although I can see where you are coming from there. I was hoping that there was something in the Intent being returned to the Delivered message broadcast receiver that would identify the individual outgoing messages. Having said that I will have a play with your idea and report back.

Comment: I had a go at creating new Intents with a putExtra() identification added to each and then used them to create new PendingIntents for each message. However the Intent that arrives at the Broadcast Receiver does not have this or any other value I could identify as pertinent. I can see that it would be possible in some circumstances to create multiple BroadcastReceivers and use different Actions to call them but this does not fit well with a situation where I have an unknown number of SMS messages to send in a batch. I may have to resort to just counting them which is a bit feeble.